# C++ Automatically Implemented Functions and the ODR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, standards-compliance

Long explanation follows, question at bottom.

My question specifically refers to the current C++ draft standard (but also the current 'main' standard) found [here](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf). More specifically, section 3.2 point 6 (page 35) states `each deﬁnition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens`, with regard to member functions and the ODR.

I recently encountered the following problem in a project while I was adding a new data analysis.

I was writing a file, A.cpp. I created a small dummy struct to hold some Data. In this example, I will call it `Data`.

```
namespace Example {
struct Data {
    //etc
};
//Use Data
};
```

However in anther file, B.cpp, there was already a struct called `Data` inside the `Example` namespace. The compiler generates `Data::~Data();` for both classes, which in turn calls the destructors of their respective members. The definition in B.cpp contains a vector, which when destructed caused explosions when called on `Data` structs using the layout defined in A.cpp. While both structs appear to work correctly, with no compile time errors, it appears that at link time the linker would pick one definition and use that, ignoring the other definition. (Hence caused explosions on `Data` objects inside of A.cpp)

No warning is issued under GCC or under MSVC. **When optimisation is enabled the problem does not occur** (the functions are inlined, no link time confusion).

My question is, the standard only states that the behaviour is undefined `If D is a template and is deﬁned in more than one translation unit`.
Either I have misunderstood the standard, and the undefined behaviour is allowed to silently occur; or both GCC and MSVC are silently accepting something they shouldn't (and should either refuse to produce an output or issue a warning) (The current situation is undefined and inconsistent behaviour without a diagnostic).

Could someone please help me understand how this is different to conflicting definitions of functions that are not defined in classes (which do cause warnings/errors).

Comment: It's an ODR violation, but such a violation is "ill-formed; no diagnostic required". The compiler doesn't have to tell you about it.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be defined in 3.2 point 4. Point 6 seems to deal with member functions and does not state that it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ok, it's undefined rather than IFNDR (though both really mean the same thing). The compiler-generated member functions are implicitly `inline`, which means that the two functions violate ODR because of the point you raised at the beginning of your question: *each deﬁnition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens*.

Comment: But if it doesn't state that the behaviour is undefined, shouldn't a diagnostic be issued? While it is very easy to work around it's also very easy to make a mistake. In this case there were no **visible** methods involved, just what should have been a POD struct.

Comment: It does state that it's undefined at the end of 3.2: *If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: On closer inspection, it seems I ignored that paragraph as it started with `If D is a template`. But it seems you are correct. This weekend I'll see if I can write a patch to force either g++ or ld to issue a diagnostic for the special case of destructors (simple because it seems to be especially insidious) This is closer to the answer than Tony D's, so if you put that up I'll mark it. :)

Comment: You already have UB because `Data` has external linkage (being a member of a namespace with default external linkage), see [basic.link]/4 and the ODR [basic.def.odr] also applies to class types (both classes must consist of the same sequence of tokens and so on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone please help me understand how this is different to conflicting definitions of functions that are not defined in classes (which do cause warnings/errors).

The difference is that function definitions inside a class are implicitly nominally *inline*, which inhibits the compiler warnings if the function's encountered again.  That doesn't mean the compiler has to inline them - it may decide using whatever heuristics not to bother, or it may simple never inline at some optimisation levels.  Anyway, if you link code that's seen different definitions of nominally inline non-member functions you have exactly the same problem.

See 3.2/6

> There can be more than one definition of a **class type** ... in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements.
>
> — each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
>
> [others requirements]

More generally, you should have put your code into **anonymous namespaces**... they're designed to prevent cross-translation-unit problems of this kind.

Comment: 3.2/4 seems to deal with non-inline functions, and states only that inline functions must be defined in every translation unit where they are used. In this case each function has a single definition within the translation unit where it is used.

Comment: James: right you are - the relevant section's 3.2/6 as per edits above.

Comment: Do the implicitly-defined functions consist of tokens? (I'd argue it's UB because the ODR also applies to classes; but I'm not sure if it applies to implicitly-defined functions.)

Comment: @DyP: interesting point re implicit and tokens... I haven't noticed anything in the Standard that clarifies that, so I'd agree conflicting class definitions is a sounder explanation.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what is being multiply-defined, it's undefined behavior to do it.  And undefined behavior can result in anything--including a working program with no diagnostics from the compiler or runtime.  Defining the same name in two different ways is not well-formed code, regardless of whether it is a member function, a free function, a struct or class, a global variable, etc.

Comment: To clarify, could you point out where in the standard this is classed as undefined behaviour? I included what I believed to be the relevant section of the C++ standard but it does not appear to cover this situation.